# Elementary-ish geometric proof of Hirzebruch signature theorem for Riemannian 4-manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes, index-theory

The [Hirzebruch signature theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch_signature_theorem) tells us that for a smooth compact oriented 4-manifold, the signature $\sigma(M)$ is proportional to the first Pontryagin number of $M$:
$$
3\sigma(M)= p_1(M) = k \int_M \mathrm{tr}(R^2)
$$
for some appropriate constant $k$ (for the purposes of this question, take the integral to be the definition of $p_1$, though properly this uses some Chern–Weil theory to prove). The usual proof of this fact goes via a general theorem involving the [$L$-genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence). The question was recently raised in conversations as to whether this result had a more elementary geometric proof, for instance at the level of Chern's intrinsic proof of the Gauss–Bonnet theorem, with additional specialisations that are specific to dimension 4.

Some simple-minded observations:

1. We can (apparently) simplify the integral to one of the form $\int_M |W^+|^2 - |W^-|^2$ (up to a proportionality constant), using the decomposition of the curvature tensor $R$ via Hodge theory and the self- and anti-self-dual parts of the Weyl curvature, $W^\pm$.
2. Likewise, we can write the signature as the difference $b_+ - b_-$ of dimensions of a decomposition of $H^2$.

So one might conceivably be able to prove $3(b_+ - b_-) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_M |W^+|^2 - |W^-|^2$ more directly using geometric methods, but I am completely unfamiliar with this area and existing research. Clearly one can prove the result using even *fancier* methods, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is a heat-kernel proof based on the same idea as Atiyah-Singer index theorem. The proof is quite elementary, but it is really long. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I was thinking more geometric than analytic. And, if possible, taking maximum advantage of working on a 4-manifold, rather than just proving the general case with the additional assumption that $d=4$.

Comment: I think you do not really need the 4 manifold assumption here, the theorem holds for any dimension 4k manifolds. But I could be wrong. You may be right that for n=4 the proof simplifies.

Comment: @Bombyxmori the equality _as stated_ is **not** true for arbitrary $4k$-manifolds, because you need more terms involving the other Pontryagin numbers. Also, the question was specifically about $4$-manifolds in the discussion I was having, with someone whose speciality is 4-manifolds and complex surfaces.

Comment: This probably isn't quite what you're looking for, but there's a mostly elementary proof using bordism: both $\sigma(M)$ and $p_1(M)$ are oriented bordism invariants valued in $\mathbb Z$, so it suffices to compute them on a generating set for $\Omega_4^{\mathrm{SO}}\otimes\mathbb Q$. Determining that this is one-dimensional requires some input from algebraic topology but isn't all that bad; then, showing $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is a generator is straightforward, and computing $\sigma(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ and $p_1(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ is also straightforward.

Comment: @ArunDebray: Yes this is a sensible approach. I recall this is one of the proofs I learned many years ago.

Comment: @ArunDebray yes, it's not quite what the person I was talking to wanted. Checking two bordism invariants are equal on the generator is far from geometric, and I believe a big part of the desiderata was knowing that these are indeed bordism invariants by purely geometric means.

Comment: @DavidRoberts if you're willing to consider spin bordism, there are certainly bordism invariants arising from geometry, namely the index (or mod 2 index) of the Dirac operator.